# View the html file embedding flash source in web view using javafx

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to play a swf file in javafx .The file  is compatible to open  with flash player . the file is embedded in html and i tried to open that html file in webview control in 
javafx but that is not supporting that and not displaying anything.

**Can you tell me the another way so that i could display the html file embedding the flash player file in it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFx cannot play swf files.

You can open the html file embedding the flash file in an external browser [HostServices.showDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29).

You may be able to play flash embedded in a Java Swing program using [the DJ project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html).